# Adding text to slideshow made through jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Presently, i am making a slide show using jquery, which swaps and animates in different ways to make a simple slide show. However, i am interested in adding text to it, i.e. details to the various images. But i am unable to get the text on the images. Can, anyone explain me how it can be done ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to play with margin and all. I placed a div below slider and tried to move it by changing its CSS, but dont know, why its not working

Comment: How have you structured the elements in your slide show? How you can add text depends on that. Post some code, that of your HTML, and the core JS part that does the switching.

Comment: can you mention which slider you have added. else paste your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you
Place it just below slider

```
<div id='updates' style='margin-top:-Xpx;'></div> // set X accordingly
```

Then in the javascript code use

```
document.getElementById("updates").innerHTML = "This image is so n so"
```

Set whatever updates or details you wish to show. Comment if you have any confusion